# JNDI Tomcat Servelet (grails) Trying to get more attributes from the LDAP binding on authentication

Tags: tomcat, grails, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm stumped.

I am working on an existing grails project that runs as a servelet under Apache Tomcat.  Authentication is done through the JNDI realm and that's all working great.  It is a bind type authentication.

There are a number of other attributes in the active directory that is behind the LDAP connection.  I want to use these in my grails app, but I can't figure how to get to them.  Are they somewhere in the ServletRequest object or Session?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new class that opens a separate JNDI connection to LDAP.  It appears that the only thing available from tomcat from the JNDIRealm authentication is the user and the roles she is a member of.

It appears that you can do more with LDAP through tomcat as a combinedRealm and create a connection to LDAP as a data source.  I decided against this since doing the connection inside the app makes it less dependent on tomcat as a server.